# Which JDK version for Xamarin.Android? Microsoft's Mobile OpenJDK Distribution for Production?

Tags: xamarin.android

I have been using JDK 8 but recently installed VS22 and found out that automatically Microsoft sets the JDK path as their Own build Jdk. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/get-started/installation/openjdk) I cannot see any warning for "not production ready". But [article](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2021/04/06/microsoft-openjdk.aspx) from June 2021 sugegests that it is still not production ready. So not sure if we can safly use this Build. Any experience or problems?
Regarding the versions there is 11 and 17 versions? can we use version 17 or we should use v11?

[image]

And more important question? how do we update it? does Microsoft updates to newer Jdk version with each VS update?

Answer (score 1):

As this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/overview) says:

> Microsoft Build of OpenJDK binaries may contain backported fixes and
> enhancements we deem important to our customers and our internal
> users. Some of these may have not yet been formally backported
> upstream and are clearly signposted in our release notes. This allows
> us to expedite improvements and fixes while we proceed to upstream
> those changes in parallel. Updates will be free and available to every
> Java developer to deploy anywhere.

Also there is a tutorial about **Transition from Java 8 to Java 11:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/transition-from-java-8-to-java-11

Comment: I havent done myself but VS22 installation automaticaly set open JDK for me and as on the screenshot it is MS own built. So far from the tests I havent experienced any issue but I am skeptical to release on prod. Is there any known issues?

Comment: I haven't heard one  if you worried, you can check the known issues part in vs feedback https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8&q=%5BVisual+Studio+2022+version+17.1%5D&stateGroup=active&ftype=problem&sort=votes